# Javascript answer changes depending on comparison order

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, join, comparison

I'm relatively new to Javascript (learned Ruby first) but have been very confused by some strange inconsistencies I've been seeing and I'm trying to figure out what the underlying mechanisms are so I can better understand the language. One of these is that when I'm doing a comparison it shouldn't matter on which side of the === sign the two elements are, but I've seen that happen and don't understand why. Here's the example for a basic function to see if a string is sorted alphabetically or not:

This version always returns true:

```
function sorted(str) { 
  var arr = str.split("");
  return arr.sort().join('')  === arr.join('');
}

sorted('abc') // => true
sorted('cba') // => true
```

While this will return the correct answer:

```
function sorted(str) { 
  var arr = str.split("");
  return arr.join('') === arr.sort().join('');
}

sorted('abc') // => true
sorted('cba') // => false
```

I've tried to figure this out and am pretty stuck - can anyone help explain?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the most of methods of [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype), [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) manipulates the object in place. Hence, in your first snippet `arr` in the second operand of `===` is sorted already, and comparison always returns `true`.